# proof of convergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I cant figure out how to prove that this series is convergent.

I have to prove that if a sequence $(a_n)$ is positive, and that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^4$, is also convergent.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, could you more explain?

Comment: I have to prove that if a sequence {a_n} is positive, and the sum(a_n) converges, then sum(a^4 _n) also converges.

The other question is: If sum(a^4_n) converges, does sum(a_n) also converge?

Comment: Since $\sum_n a_n$ is convergent then $\lim_n a_n =0$ and then $a_n<1$ for large $n$ say $n\geq n_0$ so $a_n^4<a_n,\, \forall n\geq n_0$ so the series $\sum a_n^4$ is also convergent by comparison for the second question take $a_n=\frac{1}{n^4}$

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane that's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @mrf This question is asked several times before.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane then vote to close as a duplicate

Answer (score 3):

If each a<sub>n</sub> is positive and your series converges then it must be true that a<sub>n</sub> → 0 as n→ ∞.  So after awhile your a<sub>n</sub> are all very small numbers.  Whenever a<sub>n</sub> < 1 then a<sub>n</sub><sup>4</sup> < a<sub>n</sub>.

So once you get past all the terms that are > 1, every term of a<sub>n</sub><sup>4</sup> is smaller than the corresponding term of a<sub>n</sub>. The immediate conclusion is that ∑a<sub>n</sub><sup>4</sup> is bounded above by ∑a<sub>n</sub>.

Now you can invoke a theorem that says if b<sub>n</sub> is a monotonically increasing sequence and bounded above, it must converge.  The partial sums of 
∑a<sub>n</sub><sup>4</sup> form a monotonically increasing sequence, because each a<sub>n</sub><sup>4</sup> is positive; so adding on a new term makes each partial sum larger than its predecessor.  And we know it is bounded above by the limit of ∑a<sub>n</sub>.  So it has to converge.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, but is it possible that one of you could dumb it down a little bit, I have been at it for hours and I still don't get it fully.

Comment: If you would tell me exactly what statements or terminology are confusing you I will try to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$
converges.
Then
$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$
exists.
Call this limit $L$.

By the definition of limit,
for any $c > 0$,
there is a $n(c)$ such that
$|L-\sum_{k=1}^n a_k|
< c$
for all $n \ge n(c)$.
Therefore
$L-c < \sum_{k=1}^n a_k < L+c$
for $n \ge n(c)$.

Since the $a_k$ are positive,
for any positive integer $m$,
$(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k)^m \ge
\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^m
$
since the left-hand expression includes
the right-hand one with many extras not there.

Therefore,
for $n > n(c)$,
$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^m
\le(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k)^m 
\le (L+c)^m
$.
Since the right-hand bound
($(L+c)^m$)
is independent of $n$,
$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^m )
\le (L+c)^m$,
so
$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^m$
converges for any positive integer $m$.

By letting $c \to 0$,
this also shows that
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^m
< (\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k)^m
$.